# Xamarin forms ListView item dynamic update to GUI

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a ListView in Xamarin form and bind to Observable collection in view model, adding item dynamically to ListView is working fine by calling OnPropertyChanged event.

But after getting status update from service I'm updating corresponding ListView item status and calling OnPropertyChanged event as well as re-assigining the ListView items to it but didn't get updated GUI properly sometimes working and some times not.

Below is the sample code that I've done.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceList}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" SeparatorColor="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="4" Padding="5" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                    <Label Text="{Binding OperationStatus, Converter={x:Static local:StatusMessageConverter.Default}}" FontSize="13" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="DarkCyan" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Operation}" FontSize="10" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding OperationType}" FontSize="10" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding OperationStatus}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" IsVisible="{Binding CanStatusVisible}" FontSize="10" Margin="10,0,0,0" />                          
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

public class ServiceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceItem> ServiceList 
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceList;
        }
        set
        {
            _serviceList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ServiceList");
        }
    }

    var tempList = new ObservableCollection<ServiceItem>();
    tempList = ServiceList;
    var targetItem = from item in tempList
        where item.UniqueId == uniqueId
        select item;
    if (targetItem.Any())
    {
        var resultItem = targetItem.FirstOrDefault();
        resultItem.CanStatusVisible = true;
        resultItem.OperationStatus = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Status Message", resultMessage);
    }

    ServiceList = null;
    ServiceList = tempList;
    OnPropertyChanged("ServiceList");
} 

public class ServiceItem
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }
    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    public string OperationStatus { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
    public bool CanStatusVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does your ServiceItem class implement the INotify PropertyChanged?

Comment: I've added it to ViewModel

Comment: as @BrunoCaceiro says, your ServiceItem class needs to implement INPC in order for the UI to be notified of changes to its properties

Comment: Yep! I'm checking that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

See to it that your model class inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface(as mentioned in the above comments).

```
public class ServiceItem :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private string uniqueId,operation,operationType,operationStatus,statusMessage;
 private bool statusVisible;


 public string UniqueId { get { return uniqueId; } set { uniqueId= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(UniqueId)); } }

 public string Operation { get { return operation; } set { operation= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Operation)); } }

 public string OperationType { get { return operationType; } set { operationType= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OperationType)); } }

 public string OperationStatus { get { return operationStatus; } set { operationStatus= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OperationStatus)); } }

 public string StatusMessage { get { return statusMessage; } set { statusMessage= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(StatusMessage)); } }

 public bool CanStatusVisible { get { return statusVisible; } set { statusVisible= value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CanStatusVisible )); } }
}
```

Then your ViewModel code should look something like this:

```
var tempList = new ObservableCollection<ServiceItem>();
tempList = ServiceList;
var targetItem = from item in tempList
    where item.UniqueId == uniqueId
    select item;
if (targetItem.Any())
{
    var resultItem = targetItem.FirstOrDefault();
    resultItem.CanStatusVisible = true;
    resultItem.OperationStatus = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Status Message", resultMessage);
}

ServiceList = null;
ServiceList = tempList;
```

Once you do these changes your code should work

Comment: First two lines are bugged: tempList needs to be a **copy** of `ServiceList`, not direct assignment. As written, `ServiceList.Clear` will clear tempList - not what you intend. Last two lines: Have you tested similar code on iOS X-Forms? It might not apply in this case, but iOS tends to crash with exception *"Invalid number of items in section 0."* if do two operations on a list in a single method call. If that happens, try commenting out `ServiceList.Clear();`. Specifically I've had this happen when Remove and re-Add an item to a list - maybe okay here, because substituting a whole new list.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Actually I just copied the code from the question I didn't actually check what he was doing

Comment: OK, but you introduced a bug that did not exist in his code, when you did `ServiceList.Clear()`.  So I'm not sure what you are trying to demonstrate there. - perhaps an edit that you started to make? AFAIK, all that is needed is the changes you made to `ServiceItem` - that should cause item UIs to update as needed. I believe all his code messing directly with ServiceList can be removed. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

--- To clarify my comment on FreakyAli's good answer ---

The essential part of FreakyAli's answer is the first code snippet:

```
public class ServiceItem :INotifyPropertyChanged
...
```

Once that is done, the other code in question can be greatly simplified. I think (though I have not tested) that you can replace *all* the code Ali shows under *"Then your ViewModel code should look something like this:"* with:

```
ServiceItem resultItem = ServiceList.Where(item => item.UniqueId == uniqueId).FirstOrDefault();
if (resultItem != null)
{
    resultItem.CanStatusVisible = true;
    resultItem.OperationStatus = string.Format("{0}: {1}", "Status Message", resultMessage);
}
```

That is, it is not necessary to create a temp list, nor to manipulate `ServiceList`. When you change the property of a `ServiceItem`, that property's `RaisePropertyChanged` will trigger the needed display refresh.